# Wrong snackbar position with gesture navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, android-10.0

I work on an app which display a `Snackbar`.

This`Snackbar` working fine with the following code in my `MainActivity`:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(myLayout, "My snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setBackgroundTint(myColor)
                .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
[...]
snackbar.show();
```

Here is the display:

[image]

It working fine for every screen on every orientation and for different Android versions. For only one configuration it bugs: when the device use gesture navigation. (So lot of new phones)

In this case, `Snackbar` is dispayed with a gap between the `Snackbar` and the bottom of the screen like this:

[image]

I did not find any explanation on the web but I found this by myself.

By switching on the `Show layout bounds` options in Developer options, we can observe that the "classic" navigation bar looks like still here as if the visibility was set to `View.INVISIBLE` where we can expect `View.GONE` whatever the screen.

So, when I try to display the `Snackbar`, it appears just on top of this "invisible navigation bar".

Here is some screen with layout bounds with and without gesture navigation (in home menu):

[image]

[image]

This was test with different phone and brand (Pixel, Samsung ...) and even with emulator.

Is there a normal behavior? How can I suppress this gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me setting `GestureInsetBottomIgnored` to `true` fixed the issue:

```
snackbar.setGestureInsetBottomIgnored(true);
```

From the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar#setgestureinsetbottomignored):

> Sets whether this bottom bar should adjust it's position based on the system gesture area on Android Q and above.
> Note: the bottom bar will only adjust it's position if it is dismissable via swipe (because that would cause a gesture conflict), gesture navigation is enabled, and this gestureInsetBottomIgnored flag is false.

Comment: Yes thanks, this seems to work perfectly, thank you! I probably missed that by reading docs :)

Comment: Snackbars *should* appear with a gap, above the bottom gesture zone, as you can dismiss them by swiping. If they appear inside the zone, you can't do that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for a solution forever.